# open MainActivity by BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

my code to open MainActivity and show NOTIFICATION after the time is end by AlarmManager and
BroadcastReceiver
the   NOTIFICATION go fine but the MainActivity doesn't shown my phone android 10
this the code

```
        Intent launch_intent = new  Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        launch_intent.setComponent(new 
        ComponentName("com.example.mysajedn","com.example.mysajedn.MainActivity"));
        launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
            |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
 
       launch_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );
       context.startActivity(launch_intent);

    NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification();
    notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());
```

where the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning in Android 10 (API 29), you can no longer start activities from a background process like a BroadcastReceiver.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: first ... thanks ,is their any way to open it , if their not can make a customer  sound for the Notification , i see sum code but not work , can you tell who can i do it

Comment: No a notification is your only option if coming from a BroadcastReceiver.